# javascript and jquery not working in wordpress

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, wordpress

This is the [url](http://fusioneventmanagement.in/site/) for the html template :

All the js functions are working on this  but with with the same javascript and jQuery codes when integrating it with wordpress the url for it is [here](http://fusioneventmanagement.in)

All the js functions stop running such as : `animation , mobile meenu , smooth scrolling , scroll to top , sticky menu ..`

Can you help in this ?

Answer (score 0):

You should enqueue your Jquery scripts in functions.php file in your WP theme. Use [wp_enqueue_script()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_script/) function for this. For example, to invoke your local script.js file you should do something like this in your functions.php:

```
function invokeThemeScripts() {
    wp_enqueue_script( 'my_script', get_template_directory_uri() . '/path/to/your/script.js', array('jquery'), true);
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'invokeThemeScripts');
```

Refer to WP Codex for more details.
As in static HTML page you are calling all your scripts and styles in the head of the document(or before closing body tag for scripts), transferring to WP requires you as a developer to delegate calling your theme styles and scripts to WP.

Also, as it was mentioned before WordPress will not recognize short $ syntax for your jQuery scripts. What I always do is covering all my jQuery functions into a self-invoking function with noConflict declaration.

```
jQuery(function () {
    'use strict';
    var $ = jQuery.noConflict();

    /* your script */
});
```

Comment: can you put more highlight on this how to do it

Comment: what exactly? there may be two issues: either you didn't enqueue your script file properly in functions.php, or you are using jQuery shortcode syntax ($) in your script.js

Comment: tried everything but no success

Answer (score 0):

Wrap your code (the files: `jquery.equalheights.js` `jquery.rd-navbar.js`  `superfish.js`)in:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    // Your code here
});
```

Comment: jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    // Your code here
});

Comment: jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    // Your code here
});  i have put this on all the three files and got on sucess the dropdown meenu started working but rest of the things still not working ..